# Filter posts by taxonomy Checkbox value on each page (backend)

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, arguments, advanced-custom-fields

I have an Advanced custom field taxonomy field in the form of a checkbox, which is stored in the sidebar of each page (I believe this makes the checkbox value accessible to use in a post query) - this ACF field is called 'filter_by'

The sidebar displays a list of all the terms in a custom taxonomy and the client must use the checkbox to select one of these taxonomies (much like if it were a blog post)

They are a list 'Trip Type' taxonomies, for example

Adventure
Family
Group Travel

What I am trying to achieve is for that page to then display my custom post type results (package holiday types) based on the taxonomy they selected for that page in the backend.

The end result would be the Adventure page shows all package holidays with the taxonomy 'adventure-holidays' etc etc

I'm pretty good at the basics of php but not when we get into queries.

My attempt is this - unsurprisingly it doesn't work but it does give an idea of what I a trying to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<section class="full-width-package-filter full-width-section cream-bg">

    <div class="full-width-inner">

        <h2 class="edu_green">Our Trips</h2>
        
        
        
        <?php $filterby = get_field('filter_by', $post->ID ); ?>

        
        
          <?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'package',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'meta_key' => $filterby,
            'meta_value' => 1
          );
        
          $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
          if ($my_posts->have_posts()) { ?>
        
        
           <div class="package-listings">
                        
                <div class="listings-table-row">
        
        
        
                        <?php while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post(); ?>
                
                    
                                <div class="package-wrapper teal-bg">
                
                
                                                                                      
                                    
                                           <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                            <div class="package-home-image">
                                              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                              </a>
                                            </div>
                                           <?php endif; ?>
                                           
                                           
                            
                            
                                            <div class="result-info">
                            
                                                        <div class="home-package-title">
                                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                        </div>  
                            
                                                        <div class="home-package-excerpt"> 
                                                                    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 20, '...' ); ?></p>
                                                                    
                                                        </div>   
                            
                                                        <div class="home-package-button orange-bg">
                                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button>Read More</button></a>
                                                        </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- result info end -->
                
                                </div>
                                <!-- package wrapper end -->
                
                        
                        <?php endwhile; } ?>
              
                </div>
                <!-- Listing table row end -->
                
            </div>  
            <!-- package listings end end -->   
    </div>
    <!-- full width inner end -->
    
</section>
```

Comment: For every taxonomy, WordPress already generates for you what are called taxonomy Archive pages, which means basically, for each term in your taxonomy, a URL exists exactly as you need it: filtering all posts that were given that term.

You can override this template with your custom PHP template, following a naming convention. Or, if not, it will take the one that comes with your theme.

Comment: Read more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/#custom-taxonomy

If you have questions, happy to help :)

Comment: HI there,

Thanks for this, however, correct me if I am wrong but I don't think this will solve my problem for a couple of reasons.

Firstly, I assume I can't use my own page names. So I couldn't have website/family-tours

I would have to use the generated URL from wordpress

Secondly, as a developer, I can go in and make php templates for the terms but this isn't something the client can do.

Say they decide to add a trip type later on, as an example, 'Scottish Tours' - they just need to add the category, scottish-tours, then on their new page, check that box, and that's it. Thanks!

Comment: I could easily code out a query for each page using each specific term or use facetwp filter (which I am already using in other places) but the aim is flexibility for the client. There's also about 15 different terms an corresponding pages (crazy I know)